# Date difference query in ruby/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I have an Opportunity model that has an attribute called date_of_opportunity. I am trying to write a query where I can find every opportunity whose date is within 30 days of today. My query is:

```
 Opportunity.where("date_of_opportunity - :today < 30", today: Date.today).size
```

My dates for my opportunities are:
2018-05-06
2011-04-04
2009-04-08
2017-03-06

However when I run the query, it returns all of the dates. Does anyone have any idea what is wrong with my query? Perhaps the "30" is not a unit of days?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
Opportunity.where(date_of_opportunity: (30.days.ago)..Time.now)
```

Comment: Hi - I modified my dates so I have one date that is within 30 days: 2014-06-08. I modified your answer to Opportunity.where(date_of_opportunity: (30.days.ago)..Time.now).count but it is still returning 0. Please advise.

Comment: I just typed what you wrote and I checked the console. that actually returns all Opportunities that have dates between 5/5 and 6/4

Comment: @user1547174 Isn't that what your after, what else should it return?

Comment: if you are using this in a named scope you need to use a lambda or it will always return the same set of dates